# Exception monitoring on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

Are the any error/exception monitoring plugins that work well with Azure?

I've used AppFail.Net before and found it awesome. Any others that provide similar error reports and analytics?

Answer (score 1):

[AzureWatch](http://www.paraleap.com) is probably the top product dedicated to Azure monitoring, auto-scaling and now healing.

Do be aware that my opinion is biased as I am affiliated with the product :)

Comment: It does provide on-demand review of your Trace and EventViewer data.  Check out the Azure Diagnostics screen